# hk2: why bind(X.class).to(X.class)

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2

I am learning Java, but found the following piece of code. I am confused. What is `bind(X.class).to(X.class);` for?

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(X.class).to(X.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're configuring how you want your services to be discovered in the DI (dependency injection) system. `bind(Service).to(Contract)` is basically saying that you want to provide the `Service` as an injectable service, and want to "advertise" it as `Contract`. By "advertise", I mean what you want to be able to inject it as. For instance `Service` can be `UserRepositoryImpl`, while `Contract` can be `UserRepository` (interface). With this you would only be able `@Inject UserRepository` as that's what you advertise. The benefit of this is all the benefits that come with [programming to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Example

```java
interface UserRepository {
    List<User> findAll();
}

class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return Arrays.asList(new User("username"));
    }
}

@Path("users")
class UserResource {
    @Inject
    private UserRepository repository;

    @GET
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}

class JerseyApp extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyApp() {
        register(UserResource.class);
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(UserRepositoryImpl.class)
                    .to(UserRepository.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here the `UserRepository` is injected into the `UserResource`. When the DI system injects it, it will actually be the `UserRepositoryImpl` instance.

Comment: but as for my post, it is better to import that class or do DI on that class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "import or DI". Do you mean manually instantiating vs DI? For that, you can read any article on DI and you will see the benefits.

Comment: is there any way to inject in manually? Anything like `appBinder.get(UserResource.class)`?

Comment: Use the ServiceLocator @dmitryvim sl.inject(whatever)

Answer (score 1):

By doing that you are actually binding a new contract to a service.

```
bind(Service.class).to(Contract.class);
```

OR (binding a new contract to a service in Singleton)

```
bind(Service.class).to(Contract.class)..in(Singleton.class);
```